# how to use azure logic apps to upload files in azure data lake

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

Is there any connector to store/upload files from azure logic apps to azure data lake directly or is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box at this time.

You can use the Azure Data Lake Store SDK (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk/).

Using Azure Data Factory (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-samples/) may be more practical.

Comment: what would be best practice to create a service or job on azure which can automatically copy files from azure blob to azure data lake analytics? i am fairly new in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a connector now available for Azure Data Lake Store in Logic App.